# Deserialize JSON with class hierarchy in Gson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, org.json

I have the following class hierarchy:

```java
class A {
 public final String prefix = "A";  
}

class B extends A {
 public Long id;
 public final String prefix = "B";
 C group;
}

class C extends A {
 public Long id;
 public final String prefix = "C";
 List<A> children; //entries can be C or D
}

class D extends A {
 public Long id;
 public final String prefix = "D";
}
```

I want to create a List of `B` objects which contain a `C` object. `C` objects have a children list, that
could contain `C` as well as `D` objects. Therefore, I choose `A` as the generic for the List.
The problem is that `Gson` doesn't know that these list entries are not `A`s, but `C`s or `D`s. 
Now the question is how can I tell `Gson` which object type to use? They all have a prefix, so
iterating the tree and differentiate them by the prefix may be an option. I'm also open to Jackson or org.json solutions.

That's how I deserialize the JSON input:

```java
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<B>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<B> list= gson.fromJson(input, listType);
```

json input:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "2349",
    "prefix": "B",
    "group": {
      "id": "3456",
      "prefix": "C",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "1235",
          "prefix": "C",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "4567",
              "prefix": "D"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "9823",
          "prefix": "D"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Checkout the RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory. https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.danilopianini/gson-extras/0.2.1/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.html

Comment: But will this work with a list where I don't know the specific class of the insertion objects? I only know it could be either C or D objects.